# writing unit tests for vue-multiselect

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to work out how to write tests for [vue-multiselect](http://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect) and having trouble.

Specifically, I'm trying to "click" the input to open the dropdown (before then selecting an option), however nothing is working

I'ved tried

```
vm.$el.querySelector('.multiselect').click()
```

and in the browser:

```
document.querySelector('.multiselect').click()
```

and lots of other combinations but nothing's working.

Odd for a library which emphasises it's test coverage not to give an docs (I could find on how) to use it in unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

At last got this working, the key was `.dispatchEvent(new window.Event('focus'))` not `.focus()`.

Relevant bit of final test:

```
expect(vm.$el.querySelectorAll('input')).to.have.lengthOf(1)

vm.$el.querySelector('.multiselect').dispatchEvent(new window.Event('focus'))
await tick()
const s = vm.$el.querySelectorAll('.multiselect__element')[2].querySelector('span')
expect(s.innerText).to.equal('Science')
s.dispatchEvent(new window.Event('mousedown'))
await tick()
expect(routes_visited).to.deep.equal(['/s/3-science'])

vm.$el.querySelector('.cross').click()
await tick()
expect(routes_visited).to.deep.equal(['/s/3-science', '/'])
```

(note my component changes the `vue-router` route, so I'm `watch`ing routes and pushing into `routes_visited` in the test to track changes.)